# Implement a chat app with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

All messages are ordered by message time asc (the bottom is the newest). All the messages are shown with `UITableView`. It will show 50 messages default, and load 20 more messages when pull down. How to implement this with `CoreData NSFetchedResultsController`? Does `NSFetchedResultsController` support pull-down paging?

**I think it is NOT a good idea to do like this:**

- Set `NSFetchRequest.fetchLimit` to 50
- Call `performFetch` method of `NSFetchedResultsController`
- When pull down, set `NSFetchRequest.fetchLimit` to 70, 90, etc.
- Call `performFetch` method of `NSFetchedResultsController` again
- Reload the whole table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting fetchLimit you could set batchSize, and let `NSFetchedResultsController` handle how it loads objects into memory.

Otherwise you'll have to update your fetchRequest and performFetch again.

Answer (score 4):

Before brainstorming on technical aspect of implementation it is very beneficial to carefully work out UX and overall design of the app. Here are some things that you might need to address while developing chat app:

1. Can message bubbles overlap?
2. Do you need dynamically displayed stuff like timestamps, typing animation etc.?
3. How would you organize partial fetch of the data so network will be used carefully?
4. Do you need to animate any objects in chat? (message bubbles insert, deletion and update). I mean some advanced animation that use `UIDynamics`.

Features listed above can be a real problem to implement with UITableView. While with UICollectionView you have all the power of custom layouts and batch updates.

*For ideas listed in this post should give a credit to one of Viber Messanger developers who raised this problems on one popular russian language resource.*

Comment: Thank you. But the only thing I want to know is: how to implement pull-load mechanism with NSFetchedResultsController. In this demo, I only care about local data storage and display, neither animations, chat bubbles, and any other thing that a chat app must have. That is another subject.

Comment: @keenle can you please paste a link to that russian article/discussion ?

Comment: @Fawkes, it was a long time ago, and I cannot recall which article I was referring back then. Most probably I was talking about this one from habrhabr: https://habr.com/post/225079/. Please look at the conversations in the comments to the article.